# Zeoslib won't allow switching database?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, access-violation, zeos

I use Zeoslib components to interact with my SQLite database file. I have several SQLite database files in a folder. So, I want to be able to open any one of them using Zeoslib component. However, it won't let me. It opens the first database successfully but any database file I open after that, I get access violation error. For the life of me, I simply can't figure it out WHY.

Here is how I open database file.

```pascal
procedure TMainFrm.Open1Click(Sender: TObject);
var currdb:string;
begin
 OpenDlg.InitialDir := BaseDir;
 if OpenDlg.Execute = true then
 begin
      currdb := Extractfilename(OpenDlg.FileName);
      DataModule1.ZConnection1.Disconnect;
      DataModule1.ZConnection1.Protocol := 'SQLite-3';
      DataModule1.ZConnection1.Database :=baseDir + currdb;

      DataModule1.Query1.SQL.Clear;
      DataModule1.Query1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM MyTable'); // <<<<--- ZConnection1 is Query1 database connection.

      DataModule1.ZConnection1.Connect; // <<<<<-------Here is where I get ACCESS VIOLATION all the time.
      UpdateGrid; // <<<<<<<----- Here is where the Query is executed and the DBGrid is updated.
 end;
end;
```

I don't know why this is. Is this mean I can't switch database from another using Zeoslib component?

Comment: You can try it with  `ZConnection1.Protocol:='sqlite-3';` instead of `'SQLite-3'` .

Comment: @moskito-x Oh you are KIDDING me. I spent a whole day beating my head against the wall all because of few letters were uppercase. OMG!!! I thought it wouldn't matter, but apparently it does.

Comment: Good to know `ZConnection1.Protocol` is case sensitive. And as a note, it is a good behavior to close the dataset, before disconnect. Do not trust always the automatic by "database disconnect". `if Query1.Active then ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `TZConnection.Protocol` value capitalization. Change the `Protocol` value from `SQLite-3` to [`sqlite-3`](http://sourceforge.net/p/zeoslib/code-0/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/plain/ZPlainSqLiteDriver.pas#l1345).